# Chainload a LinuxOS present in a GPT disk

Tags: linux, windows, boot, grub2, grub4dos

booting from a MBR disk...
how to ***chainload*** a LinuxOS present in another disk (let's say Disk#2)

Disk#2 was a boot disk from other computer,
is a GPT disk with a single Linux distro installed
I want to *chainload* it from **bootmgr** or from **grub4dos**
but any try to load the Disk#2/Partition#1/EFI/boot/BOOTx64.EFI
gave me an error of incompatible binary image...

?any ideas??

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, that’s not going to happen. EFI applications run on EFI, not in real mode. There is one working EFI “emulator”: Clover. It is overkill for your use case.

You can just set up a proper Linux boot manager/load to boot the Linux kernel regularly. On GRUB, that would be the `linux` config command. GRUB 2 can easily access GPT.

grub4dos however is very outdated. It is unlikely to support GPT. If, in fact, it does, you could use it, too. Just boot the kernel.

(Also, do not forget the correct command line and possibly the initramfs. Check the original boot config on Disk#2 perhaps.)

Comment: good info... but I'm sure I can launch a protected process if boot(ed) in real mode... why not launch a efi shell and let it 'discover' the /EFI folder...

Comment: your suggestion of a proper linux boot (add the linux partition entry to grub*) was my first idea... but when I change the 2nd disk I would have to reconfig... and that can be avoided if I found a way to call the EFI firmware and let it do his 'thing'... ;-)

Comment: when I have the time I'll do some experiment with REFIND... it already solved me a problem a few years ago with some toshiba x86 tablets...

Answer (score 0):

If you need Linux running that does not support UEFI, run Linux as a virtual machine,

On a decent host computer, that works really well.

I do that here.